# Why is stopping potential independent of frequency of photoelectron?

Tags: atomic-physics, home-experiment, intensity

All the books and internet articles I have read so far claimed that the stopping potential and the maximum kinetic energy attained by a photoelectron is independent of the intensity with which the light emanates.

But stopping potential is proportional to the frequency of light and,

$$I=\frac{nh\nu}{A}$$
where

- $n$ = number of photons incident per unit time
- $h$ = Planck's Constant
- $\nu$ = the frequency of light
- $A$ = area

How does this make sense?

Comment: so what are you expressing or expecting from that equation ?

Answer (score 0):

That is the whole point of photoelectric effect experiment,
This experiment proves that particle nature of light exists,
Here light acts particles, with energy packets, i.e have discrete energy, with energy equal to $E= h \nu$, $\nu$=frequency,
Since this frequency dependent energy is given to free electrons in metal, they are ejected from surface, hence energy required to stop them is also frequency dependent and not intensity dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a great one and it's at the heart of the photoelectric effect, which was crucial in the development of quantum mechanics.

The equation you've written, I=nhν/A, describes the intensity of the light beam, where `n` is the number of photons per unit time, `h` is Planck's constant, `ν` is the frequency of the light, and `A` is the area over which the light is spread. This equation tells us that the intensity of the light beam is proportional to the number of photons hitting the area per unit time, and each photon carries energy `hν`.

However, the key point here is that each individual photon interacts with individual electrons. The energy of each photon is `hν`, and this energy is transferred to an electron when the photon is absorbed. If the energy `hν` is greater than the work function of the material (the energy required to remove an electron), then the electron can be ejected from the material. This is the photoelectric effect.

The maximum kinetic energy of the ejected electron is given by the difference between the energy of the photon and the work function of the material. This is often written as K_{max} = hν-φ where `K_{max}` is the maximum kinetic energy of the electron, `hν` is the energy of the photon, and `φ` is the work function of the material.

The stopping potential is the minimum voltage needed to stop the ejected electrons. It is related to the maximum kinetic energy by V_{stop} = K_{max}/e where `e` is the charge of an electron.

Now, the intensity of the light beam affects the number of photons hitting the area per unit time, but it does not affect the energy of each individual photon. Therefore, increasing the intensity of the light beam increases the number of electrons ejected (the photoelectric current), but it does not increase the maximum kinetic energy of the ejected electrons. This is why the stopping potential (and the maximum kinetic energy of the photoelectrons) is independent of the intensity of the light.

I hope this helps clarify the relationship between the stopping potential, the intensity of the light, and the frequency of the light in the context of the photoelectric effect.